# Lazy Var giving Error for NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller

This code gives error while initializing fetchResultController

```
lazy var fetchedResultController:
NSFetchedResultsController =
  self.surfJournalfetchedResultController()

func surfJournalfetchedResultController()
-> NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>{}
```

Comment: Add the error message you get

Comment: value of type '(NSObject)' ->() -> viewcontroller has no member 'surfJournalfetchedResultController'